# Close a hamburger menu by clicking anywhere

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have seen that this question has been answered a number of times, I can't get it to work for me.
I want to put a hamburger menu on to my site and have it close when anywhere but the menu is clicked on the page.
The JQuery I am using is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".cross").hide();
    $(".menu").hide();
    $(".hamburger").click(function() {
        $(".menu").slideToggle("slow", function() {
            $(".hamburger").hide();
            $(".cross").show();
        });
    });

    $(".cross").click(function() {
        $(".menu").slideToggle("slow", function() {
            $(".cross").hide();
            $(".hamburger").show();
        });
    });

});
```

I'd really appreciate advice on how to add a close function.
Thanks,
Shaun.

Comment: `$(":not(.cross)").click(function() {
        $(".menu").hide();
    });` try

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you can use this function

```
// when click on window
function actionwindowclick(elem , action){
    $(window).on('click',function(e){
        if (!$(elem).is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
            && $(elem).has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
        {
            action();
        }
    });
}
```

and use this function

```
actionwindowclick('.cross , .hamburger', function(){
    $(".hamburger").hide();
});
```

**Sample**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $(".cross").click(function(){
    $('.hamburger').show();
  });
  
  
  
  // run function here
  actionwindowclick('.cross , .hamburger', function(){
         $(".hamburger").hide();
    });
});


// when click on window
function actionwindowclick(elem , action){
 $(window).on('click',function(e){
  if (!$(elem).is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
         && $(elem).has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
     {
   action();
     }
 });
}
```

```css
.hamburger{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="cross">Cross Div</div>
<div class="hamburger">
  Hamburger Div
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain how this works to the author, please? Code dumps are bad practice

Answer (score -2):

use focusout

$( '#p' ).focusout(function() { 
 $('#myDiv').hide(); })